# Google Docs Add-ons Help Menu

Tags: google-apps-script, documentation, google-docs-api

I am developing a Google Doc Add-on, and can't find the documentation for how to edit the content of the automatically added "Help" tab. Does anyone know where this documentation is, or how to edit that tab?

Comment: You have to edit post-tooltip. Review [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style). And, post-tooltip can be edited by ui feature of Add-ons.

Comment: @user1989 the documentation is really confusing... I want the "Help" tab, not a url linking from a "Learn More" tab!

Comment: Try to follow the link mentioned in an answer. I hope you will get it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's quite confusing to me too, not so clear. And regarding the help menu, the description you find in help tab is nothing but a post-install tip message. So, if you write something in post-install tip message, it will eventually appear in help tab.

Now how to edit post-tool tip?
Post-install tip is provided when you publish your add-on. Read the description of [publishing instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish). Read the steps. Also read the [style guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style) for more information.

Comment: Whenever you find any answer right, just accept it and vote  up if whenever you will have an enough reputation, so future viewers can trust this answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this! I agree, Google should really improve their documentation regarding publishing add-ons and extensions.